# Encapsulating asynchronous actions in functions

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I've faced an ambiguous situation with asynchronous functions in Tornado.

The system I've been working on receives only POST requests and serves them asynchroniously. But now i must add GET request handling for serving IE8 users.
The problem is that GET request functionality is *exactly* the same as in post request.

I don't want co simply copy-paste my code, so i've came to the following solution:

```
class ExampleHandler(BaseHandler):

    def _request_action(self):
        """ Function that incapsulates all actions, that should be performed in request
        """
        yield self.motor.col1.insert({"ex1": 1})
        raise Return

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        """ GET request handler - need for IE8- users. Used ONLY for them
        """
        self._request_action()

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        """ POST handling for all users, except IE8-
        """
        self._request_action()
```

I have a lot of doubts about async decorators. Is it enough to wrap GET/POST handlers in decorators, and put all actions that should be performed in a synchronously working function? Or i should wrap it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `yield` a [`Future`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.Future) inside a function, you have to wrap it with [`@gen.coroutine`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.coroutine).

So, wrap `_request_action` with `@gen.coroutine`

```
@gen.coroutine
def _request_action(self):
    """ Function that incapsulates all actions, that should be performed in request
    """
    result = yield self.motor.col1.insert({"ex1": 1})
    raise gen.Return(result)  # that is how you can return result from coroutine
```

And also, all coroutines must be called by `yield`:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    """ GET request handler - need for IE8- users. Used ONLY for them
    """
    result = yield self._request_action()
    # do something with result, if you need

@gen.coroutine
def post(self):
    """ POST handling for all users, except IE8-
    """
    result = yield self._request_action()
    # do something with result, if you need
```